# Conditional Jump Syntax

Tags: assembly

I have encountered some assembly x86_64 code which uses the following syntax for conditional jumps:

```
JE >
    MOV RAX, RBX
:

JE >1
    MOV RBX, RAX
1:
```

This is repeated throughout the procedure.

I found the code from this LDE.
https://github.com/BeaEngine/lde64

The readme says "It was implemented to be assembled with goasm assembler".

What do the characters after the JE instructions do?

How can labels repeat themselves?

How can I convert this to be compiled by MASM?

Comment: Which precise instruction set and which precise assembler is this? Please [edit] your question to clarify.

Comment: Looks like this is discussed in the goasm [docs](http://www.godevtool.com/GoasmHelp/GoAsm.htm#jumpu).

Comment: @DavidWohlferd So to confirm it either looks up or down for the first match. To convert this I would need to replace all labels and jump with unique ones?

Comment: I have never used goasm, so any advice I offered beyond the docs would be a guess.